# How do I use JQuery's event handler use a textbox with a submit button?

Tags: jquery

I'm a new JQuery user and have the task of submitting text via a textbox and a submit button on a web browser window as a list item that adds to the end of an unordered list.

**HTML:**

```
 <ul class="list">
      <li></li> 
 </ul>
```

**JS:**

```
 var text = $('text');
 var submit = $('submit');
```

Question: What JQuery event handlers would I use to submit the text in the textbox and submit my text to a server using an HTTP request?

Any advice and coding examples would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain your situation a bit more? You don't need any event handler to write into the text field or to submit the data, that's what input fields and submit buttons already do by default. Btw, if you want to select elements by class, you have to use the class selector: `$('.text')`.

Comment: Is normal form syntax not good enough for you? Or did you mean you want to send the data asynchronously?

Comment: @popnoodles: I want to send it asynchronously.

Comment: @FelixKling - +1, That's a valid point, seems there are more and more question about sending forms with javascript when the default action does exactly the same, some people even use ajax, then they redirect to a "thank you" page or something similar, that does'nt make sense as it's exactly what you'd do without JS ?

Comment: I updated my answer to be _specific as possible_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a form put all form fields inside it then bind submit button

```
var text   = $('.text');
var submit = $('.submit');

submit.click(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url : 'yourServerURL',
        type: 'POST',
        data:  text.val()
     });
});
```

Comment: What is form in this example? I want to make the text I submit send to a server with an HTTP request then appear on the screen as a list item at the end of an unordered list.

Comment: Any input is appreciated. Thank you for responding @Sushil

Comment: If you want use ajax call to submit your data then instead of form submit use jquery.ajax.

Comment: How do I make sure the text is passed using JQuery's Ajax?

Comment: If I clicked the submit button, add _(POST request)_ the text from the textbox to an unordered list as a list item... would I use "**data: text.val()**" or should I use the success and error keys?

Comment: success or error keys are to handle response from server . if request is success full then success will be called otherwise error method will be called

Answer (score 3):

Actually, classes are :

```
var text   = $('.text');
var submit = $('.submit');
```

Then you'd do :

```
submit.on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
       url : '/server/myURL/',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {myData : text.val()}
   });
});
```

etc...

Read the documentation and look at answers at SO to learn more?

Comment: Thank you @adeneo. Are you referring to the AJAX documentation?